How to store large arrays in core data?
I have an entity called AudioFile in my core data database. It has attributes like name, artist, file extension and more which are all string. An audio file is unique as long as both the names and the file extensions are different.
I also have a struct called “UpNextItem” which have identical attributes to “AudioFile” entity from core data except that there’s an additional id property of type UUID since a user can add multiple instances of the same audio file.
How do I store a very large array of up next items to disk? Using JSONEncoder is extremely slow too with an almost 140% of cpu usage and my app hangs for almost 2-3 seconds.
Or is there a better way to store this? Since "AudioFile" and "UpNextItem" are almost identical?
I’m expecting the user to have in the range of 10000 or more of up next items in an array so it’s actually plenty of data to be stored in an array.
func saveUpNextItems() {
        if let items = try? JSONEncoder().encode(upNextManager.upNextItems) {
        do {
            try items.write(to: FileManager.upNextQueueURL.appendingPathComponent("upNextItems"))
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}


You'd create a new Core Data entity called UpNextItem which would have an identifier and a (non-deleting) Many:1 relationship to an AudioFile. Then you would have a Playlist entity that has an ordered 1:Many relationship (with cascading delete) to UpNextItem.
NSOrderedSet is a bit of a headache to work with, and for small collections it's often easier to just attach an "order" integer property to the entities and then sort them. But for something on the scale you're describing, an ordered relationship with NSOrderedSet would be the right tool.
Managing 10k items is exactly when you want something like Core Data or SQLite. You don't want to be serializing things on that scale to text formats, or even binary plist formats.

The issue is that my app only has one up next queue with over 10k up next items. Is there a better way to architect my core data store since all I’m reading is that it is bad design to force a singleton pattern for a data store (I.e. in this case, having only one next queue)

I don't understand what you mean by "force a singleton pattern for a data store" here. If there is only one playlist, there only needs to be one playlist. If it ever needs more, you could have more.

Is there a way to force core data to ensure there’s only one up next queue at any given time?

No, but it's not necessary. Don't make two. Many things in Cocoa are done this way. There's nothing requiring there be only one UserDefaults. You can make multiple. But we generally just use one, and it's usually a bad idea to make more. Same for NotificationCenter. If you want to keep track of the one you use (rather than querying for it), you can keep track of its objectID in UserDefaults. And in the future, this will allow you to have multiple lists if needed, but you don't have to have multiple lists.
